# How to determine what city I'm in using my mac's location and python?

Tags: python, weather

I'm trying to create a basic weather web app. The idea is that it will automatically determine your location and then display the forecast for that area. I'm sure this has already been done, I'm just doing it for fun. Are there any python libraries or ways of doing this? Upon googling for a solution, I couldn't find anything. On stack overflow the only similar question is related to android.

Comment: try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geoip2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as this

```
 import geocoder
 g = geocoder.ip('199.7.157.0')
 g = geocoder.ip('me')
 g.latlng
 g.city
```